# Creating static library in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode6, static-libraries

I have created a static library by referring to the 
 [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) in iOS. It works fine with iPhone5 simulator and device. However, when I tried to run with iPhone5s, iPhone6 and above I am getting `apple mach-O linker error`

Comment: Missing 64-bit support.

Comment: Yes @RoNiT do you know how to solve this issue?